# Add Value To Input Box

Tags: html

Hello guys I wanted to know that is there a way to tell a input box to append something at the start

```
<input type="text" label="false" placeholder="Article Source URL" name="url" id="7TkwumNLSSXC9hJ7d" data-schema-key="url" required="" pattern="https?://.+">
```

in it we are telling it the pattern but is there a way that a input box always append https:// at the start without using jquery ??

Comment: use attribute value to put value on start.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can use the `value` attribute to give it a default value of `http://`, but HTML provides nothing that would change its value automatically if that was removed.

You can do that with JavaScript (adding it on blur or when the form is submitted, for example) and libraries like jQuery can make that simpler.